# keyup and change function on IE

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net-mvc

I have a change event and a keyup event. I noticed that when there is a keyup event change event does not fire on IE 8. I have a function that I really need to execute on change but not on keypress. Is there a way to do it? Any advice or suggestion is highly appreciated.

```
 $('#txtbox').on('keyup', function () {        
        onKeyUp();
    }).change(function () {
        onChanged();
    });
```

Here's the code.
I should do something on change event that I should not call each time the user presses a key.

Comment: The change event fires when the text box loses focus. It doesn't fire every type a character is typed.

Comment: can you paste your code here ?

Comment: @Dismissile: change event is not firing on IE even if it loses its focus on the text box. I have a keypress and keydown event. Is it what causes the change event not to execute?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `input` event for this:

```
$(':text').on('input', callback);
```

or you can use `setTimeout()` or `clearTimeout()`:

```
var a='';
$(':text').on('input', function(){
    clearTimeout(a);

    a = setTimeout(function(){
           console.log('done');
        },500);
});
```

---

#### [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/B7fY5/)

Comment: what does callback do? set Timeout.. it just allows the user to input up to 500ms? What if it's more than the specified time? Thanks for your response.

Comment: you can try the fiddle, if you type you can see the output only came after you stop the typing.

Comment: I am using @html.textboxfor.

 $('#txtbx1,#txtbx2,#txtbx3,#txtbx4').on('keypress', function (e) {
        onKeypress();
    }).on('click', function () {
        onClick();
    }).change(function () {
        onChange();
    }).find(':text').on('input', function () {
        clearTimeout(a);

        a = setTimeout(function () {
            console.log('done');
        }, 500);
    });
It's not working for me. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Avoid settings the value but set innerText instead.

```
// Set value for IE without clearing the "changed" flag
this.innerText = val;

// Set value for everyone else
if ( this.value != val ) {
    this.value = val;
}
```